# Python3 dynamic sqlite select query

Tags: python, sqlite

I am struggling to replicate an sqlite SELECT query.

```
sqlite> select "de-515" from balances where id = '1';
de-515
0.1
sqlite>
```

works with no issue from sqlite, however when I try building this query into a python script nothing I put together seems to work. I have tried the following with the intent of setting a python variable equal to the `0.1` value that is seen above.

```
elementBalQuery = 'SELECT "%s" FROM balances WHERE id="%s"'
cursor.execute(elementBalQuery, (elementName,userId))
curBal = cursor.fetchall()
print("curBal = ", curBal)
```

this results in

```
Traceback (most recent call last): 
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 0, and there are 2 supplied.
```

Also this fails

```
cursor.execute("SELECT %s FROM balances WHERE id=?", % (elementName), (userId))

cursor.execute("SELECT %s FROM balances WHERE id=?", % (elementName), (userId))
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I have attempted several other ways to craft this query and cannot figure out what I am missing. I come from a bash background where I would be able to easily set a var equal to the output of a sqlite query.

How would, using a dynamic query, I select a row using a variable name?

Answer (score 1):

You need to combine string formatting *and* parameter substitution to create a query that can be executed safely.

```py
# Sqlite uses question marks for value placeholders
# and double-quotes for identifiers.  See
# https://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html

sql = 'SELECT "%s" FROM balances WHERE id = ?'
# Use string formatting (%, .format, f-string) to add the column name(s)
sql = sql % column_name
# Use parameter substitution to add the value(s) to ensure correct quoting of values
result = cursor.execute(sql, (1,))
```

There is an alternative form for value placeholders

```py
sql = 'SELECT "%s" FROM balances WHERE id = :id'
sql = sql % column_name
result = cursor.execute(sql, {'id': 1})
```

Answer (score 1):

Define your query like this:

```
query = f'''SELECT {elementName} FROM {tableName} WHERE id={userId}'''
```

and then:

```
cursor.execute(query)
```

Parameters should be assigned before query construction.

Note that this type of formatting is not supported in python2

Comment: I am using python3. For some reason when I try this I get a syntax error.

`sqlite3.OperationalError: near ")": syntax error`

Comment: My exact implementation was:

`balQuery = f'''SELECT {elementName} FROM balances WHERE id={userId}'''`

Comment: Thank you, Let me investigate more

Comment: I actually got it to work with `cursor.execute("SELECT (" + elementName + ") FROM balances WHERE id=?", (userId))`

Answer (score 1):

the below answers also worked, I was able to get it working with `cursor.execute("SELECT (" + elementName + ") FROM balances WHERE id=?", (userId))` one of the other issues I found is that some of the elementName entries there was a hyphen that I think the script didn't like. eg. `rf-431` I removed all hypens from the DB and got this working, thanks to all for promptly answering.